# Node JS I/O return function

Tags: node.js, io

I have a problem to code in node JS with I/O

Function 1 sends message to Function 2 and takes its result.
Function 2 searches files-name form disk and return that name.

In this situation I get message "undefined". after that in console log show that file name written in function 2.

I want to take message file-name at "undefined".

If you don't mind, give me some example.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Show us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: You have a problem with asynchronity. Function 2 continues running in the background, but already returned to Function 1. Therefore Function 1 cannot get the result returned. It's a big subject. As SLaks wrote: Welcome to the wonderful **world** of async. You will need to learn a lot about asynchronity. It's a difficult concept for many.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving me good advices.

I took all of yours, but "callback function" is the best choice I think.

After the project, using Node.js with centos6, async rarely makes race condition.

So, I used callback function for stability.